# jQuery/Ajax: run alert() as the page/datatable starts to load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good day!

I have a problem (pretty basic to some).

**Situation:** I have a file 'search_employee.php' and I am retrieving a large amount of data to my [DataTable](https://datatables.net/). I want to alert("Please be patient as the table loads large amount of data")

...as the page starts to load (consider browser's loading logo),

[image: page loading]

and not after being loaded

[image: page loaded]

**Note:**
I already have some jquery/ajax codes on some of my files that does filtering before loading large amount of records. In this case, I intentionally want to load large data just to test if there's a way to run a script as the page starts to load. No passing of data, no search/filtering. Just load. I'm sorry guys, I'm just curious =)

**Question:** How am I going to run alert() as the page/datatable starts to load? (no data to be passed, just load)

I've seen some jquery/ajax codes around but I don't know how to do it on my case.

Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Alert won't work. Make the page load fast and display a message on your page. You use ajax then to retrieve your db records and update the page content , and use pagination..

Comment: I am using jquery datatables, Default display to show is 50 rows. I have 23k+ records in all.

Comment: Why would you want to pull 23k records at once ? No familiar with datatables but the pagination  (50) is done front end meaning your pulling all records then hiding it on the page. You may want to do the opposite , take 50 only from your db,if the user needs more request the following 50 ect..this way you will improve a lot the speed. Look at datatable server side.processing via ajax.

Comment: Thank you sir.. actually I already have search filtering (jquery/ajax) on some of my pages and it does your suggestions. In this case, I intentionally load a large data to test if there's a way to run a script once the page starts to load without data passing.. just load.. i updated my post for more understanding..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show this in page loading time . You call the alert on on ready function in jQuery.

Example given below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.this will loads a page loads.
  alert("Please be patient as the table loads large amount of data");
});
```

For more example about [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) you will get here

Comment: I've already tried that sir.. the alert pops after the page/table is being loaded

Comment: Please edit your question with table loading script.

Comment: is the data-table is populating through ajax or not ?

Comment: I exactly don't know sir.. I just use the default jquery datatable settings. I just provide the query and that's it. I will provide a link to my post regarding datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Place this alert `alert("Please be patient as the table loads large amount of data")` outside of this `$(document).ready(function(){});` function.

Comment: I would be work if you place this code in <head> alert('place here'); <head> and outside of ready function.

Comment: still the same... your suggestions do these: "page loads > long loading pause > alert pops > table results". I need something like: "page loads > alert pops >  long loading pause > table results".. anyway, your effort is much appreciated sir. thank you.